# Ansible: run play only if tagged with specific tag

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Using Ansible `ansible 2.4.2.0` I'm trying to run only a certain play from the main playbook (`main.yml`)

```
---
# main playbook for cluster deployment

  # initial configuration of OS same for all hosts
- name: Cluster Deployer playbook
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - { role: common, tags: ['initial_config'] }


  # configuration specific for loadbalancers hosts group
- name: Cluster Deployer playbook - Load Balancer setup
  hosts: loadbalancers
  roles:
    - { role: loadbalancers_setup, tags: ['setup_loadbalancer'] }

  # configuration specific for db-servers hosts group
- name: Cluster Deployer playbook - Database servers setup
  hosts: db-servers
  roles:
   - { role: db_servers_setup, tags: ['setup_db_server'] }

  # configuration specific for web-servers hosts group
- name: Cluster Deployer playbook - Web Servers setup
  hosts: web-servers
  roles:
   - { role: web_servers_setup, tags: ['setup_web_server'] }
```

Here's my `hosts` file

```
[loadbalancers]
192.168.99.10

[db-servers]
192.168.99.2

[web-servers]
192.168.99.3
192.168.99.4
```

I'm calling the playbook with the command

```
ansible-playbook main.yml --inventory hosts --tags initial_config
```

The problem is that Ansible runs all plays from that playbook even though I've requested only those with tag `initial_config` in the `roles` section. I've tried with setting the `tags` section under `hosts` but with no luck.

Is it possible to define tags on this level without the need for tagging individual tasks in roles?
I'm new to Ansible so if there is a better way of writing playbooks, I'm all ears.

Comment: Could be syntax issue, try using "" : ansible-playbook main.yml --inventory hosts --tags "initial_config"

Comment: Same thing with the quotes @karthikvee

Answer (score 2):

The "tag" directive is misplaced in your code.

Your code should look like so:

```
---
# main playbook for cluster deployment

  # initial configuration of OS same for all hosts
- name: Cluster Deployer playbook
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - common
  tags: 
    - initial_config

  # configuration specific for loadbalancers hosts group
- name: Cluster Deployer playbook - Load Balancer setup
  hosts: loadbalancers
  roles:
    - loadbalancers_setup
  tags: 
    - setup_loadbalancer

  # configuration specific for db-servers hosts group
- name: Cluster Deployer playbook - Database servers setup
  hosts: db-servers
  roles:
    - db_servers_setup
  tags: 
    - setup_db_server

  # configuration specific for web-servers hosts group
- name: Cluster Deployer playbook - Web Servers setup
  hosts: web-servers
  roles:
    - web_servers_setup
  tags:
    - setup_web_server
```

And your ansible command should look like so:

```
ansible-playbook main.yml --inventory hosts --tags "initial_config"
```

For more information, check [Ansible's official documentation.](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_tags.html)

Comment: Still no luck, when running this playbook with `ansible-playbook main.yml --inventory hosts --tags "setup_db_server"` (or without quotes on the tag name) all plays are listed and executed in order they are written in the playbook..

Comment: @MatijaB Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48527578/2947502)

Comment: Should you include the "always" tag to also gather facts? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags-always-and-never

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have misconception of tag inheritance here:

> Tag Inheritance
>
> You can apply tags to more than tasks, but they **ONLY affect the tasks themselves**. Applying tags anywhere else is just a convenience so you don’t have to write it on every task. [Ansible documentation on tag inheritance](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_tags.html#tag-inheritance)

Try something like this:

```
- name: Cluster Deployer playbook
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: common
      tags:
       - inital_config
```